# TXT records on new DNS are not visible after nameservers change to new DNS

Tags: dns, nameserver, domain-forwarding

Basically, we have bought a domain name on register365 and webhosting on Wedos. I've changed the nameservers in register365 to nameservers provided by Wedos and I can reach the website there under the registered name fine. And so after this I expect all the other records like TXT to be managed in the Wedos DNS system too.

But the problem is, when I add new TXT record in Wedos DNS, I can't see it anywhere from the outside DNS tools.

When I tried to add the TXT record to the old DNS in register365, it's propagated and visible straight away.

I'd need to manage TXT records in Wedos, because they use it for automatic generation of LetsEncrypt certificate. I've done it manually on my Linux based on findings above, but I can't be doing it every 3 months like that.

I talked to Wedos support and they told me that I need to link all DNS records to their servers and they can't do anything with it before that's done.

So I wonder what am I missing in addition to just changing nameservers? How to make TXT records to be read from Wedos instead of register365?

List of nameservers set for the domain `novecento.ie`:

- Name Server: `ns.wedos.com`
- Name Server: `ns.wedos.cz`
- Name Server: `ns.wedos.eu`
- Name Server: `ns.wedos.net`

Comment: I can confirm that your NS records are all set correctly to the wedos name servers.   It looks like you could talk to Wedos support again.  Everything is linked to their servers.

Comment: That sounds correct, however I wonder how is it possible, that TXT records set in register365 are visible online while the same records set manually by me in Wedos DNS can't be seen. Shouldn't they be possible to set in register365 already?

Comment: Btw, thanks for editing of the question @Stephen Ostermiller. I was on a phone web and couldn't seem to set the code font on the text

Comment: @Kuba wedos likely isn't publishing the DNS entries properly.   To me, this would be a flag that there is a problem with their hosting and I would be looking to move somewhere else.

Comment: @Steve Yup, I may do that next year, since this choice was only a quick fix to another problem with register365 hosting. I just wondered about this specific behaviour - am I right to assume, that whichever DNS in a route of nameserver references publishes other records like TXT, CNAME, etc. they are simply visible by internet too? As I wouldn't expect to see those from register365 once the other nameservers are set, so I hope that register365 doesn't prevent the visibility of such TXT records further down in route.

Comment: Correct, wherever your nameservers are pointing, that is your "in-effect" DNS.

Comment: Great, thanks for clearing that up for me @Steve